# Code By Zapier: Python - How to make it return error

Tags: python, zapier

I have written some python code to fetch a http request using requests library.

How do I make it error out if, after examining response, I figure out that I have not gotten the desired data?

Please note that I want to raise error only in certain cases.

Right now, I return an output object and the step always shows a passed.

Comment: If you get a valid result but it's not the one you'd like, return `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

There's no secret sauce for Python on Zapier - If you want to raise an error, you can just [raise it](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/#raising-an-exception). How do you that depends on what situations you want to trigger an error state.

```
response = requests.get(url)

# raises for all error codes >= 400
response.raise_for_status() 
result = response.json()

# or more manually, for specific cases
if result['my_key'] != 'key_i_want':
    raise Exception('bad key')
```

Does that make sense? ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!